# Problems creating an issue in JIRA with Custom Fields with Soap Lite and perl

Tags: perl, soap, jira, soaplite

I'm banging my head against the soap api with the following code. My goal is to create a ticket with custom fields. If you comment out the custom field part this code works fine. Any idea of what's going on?

Code

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->service($wsdl);
my $token = $soap->login($_jira_user,$_jira_pass);

my $customFields = [
    {'customFieldId' => $_cf_map{'severity'},'values' => [SOAP::Data->type('string', $severity)]},
    {'customFieldId' => $_cf_map{'outage_start'}, 'values' => [SOAP::Data->type('string', $start)]},
    {'customFieldId' => $_cf_map{'no_auto_close'}, 'values' => [SOAP::Data->type('string', $no_auto_close == 1 ? 'Yes': 'No')]},
    {'customFieldId' => $_cf_map{'nco_serials'}, 'values' => [SOAP::Data->type('string', $serial_string)]},
    {'customFieldId' => $_cf_map{'services'}, 'values' => \@services},
];

my $remoteIssueHash = {
    'project' => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $_projectkey),
    'type' => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $_issuetype),
    'summary' => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $summary),
    'reporter' => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $user),
    'assignee' => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $user),
    'customFieldValues' => $customFields,
};

my $remote_issue = $soap->call('createIssue', $token, $remoteIssueHash);
print Dumper [$remote_issue->faultcode(), $remote_issue->faultstring(), $soap->transport()->status(), $remote_issue->result(), $remote_issue ]
exit();
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
      'soapenv:Server.userException',
      'org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer for {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType',
      '500 Internal Server Error',
      #big soap object
      ]
```

XML SENT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:tns2="http://exception.rpc.jira.atlassian.com" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:namesp1="http://soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns1="http://beans.soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com" xmlns:impl="http://jira.nyc.hcmny.com:8080/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
            <namesp1:createIssue>
                  <c-gensym6 xsi:type="xsd:string">Y6DQd1k2BL</c-gensym6>
                  <c-gensym8>
                        <assignee xsi:type="xsd:string">fgulotta</assignee>
                        <customFieldValues soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[5]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                              <item>
                                    <customFieldId xsi:type="xsd:string">customfield_10094</customFieldId>
                                    <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                                          <item xsi:type="xsd:string">4</item>
                                    </values>
                                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                              </item>
                              <item>
                                    <customFieldId xsi:type="xsd:string">customfield_10084</customFieldId>
                                    <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                                          <item xsi:type="xsd:string">29/Jul/11 05:46 PM</item>
                                    </values>
                                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                              </item>
                              <item>
                                    <customFieldId xsi:type="xsd:string">customfield_10100</customFieldId>
                                    <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                                          <item xsi:type="xsd:string">Yes</item>
                                    </values>
                                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                              </item>
                              <item>
                                    <customFieldId xsi:type="xsd:string">customfield_10093</customFieldId>
                                    <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                                          <item xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                                    </values>
                                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                              </item>
                              <item>
                                    <customFieldId xsi:type="xsd:string">customfield_10080</customFieldId>
                                    <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                                          <item xsi:type="xsd:string">intranet</item>
                                    </values>
                                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                              </item>
                        </customFieldValues>
                        <summary xsi:type="xsd:string">This is a test ticket.</summary>
                        <project xsi:type="xsd:string">MON</project>
                        <type xsi:type="xsd:string">31</type>
                        <reporter xsi:type="xsd:string">fgulotta</reporter>
                  </c-gensym8>
            </namesp1:createIssue>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XML RECIEVED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Body>
            <soapenv:Fault>
                  <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
                  <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer for {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType</faultstring>
                  <detail>
                        <faultData xsi:type="ns1:SAXException" xmlns:ns1="http://sax.xml.org">
                              <exception xsi:type="ns2:Exception" xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns2="http://lang.java"/>
                              <message xsi:type="xsd:string">No deserializer for {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType</message>
                        </faultData>
                        <ns3:hostname xmlns:ns3="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">deputy.811t.hcmny.com</ns3:hostname>
                  </detail>
            </soapenv:Fault>
      </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Updated** Fixed field names and put values in string arrays but still have issues.

**2nd update**
I found some java code that works against the soap service and ran my tests against that. Then I used wireshark to sniff the xml. Ignoring the multirefs its a very similar structure, but I'm not quite sure how to model it with Soap::Lite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Body>
            <ns1:createIssue soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com">
                  <in0 xsi:type="xsd:string">B2P69v5NrS</in0>
                  <in1 href="#id0"/>
            </ns1:createIssue>
            <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:RemoteIssue" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://beans.soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com">
                  <id xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <affectsVersions xsi:type="ns2:RemoteVersion" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <assignee xsi:type="xsd:string">fgulotta</assignee>
                  <attachmentNames xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <components xsi:type="ns2:RemoteComponent" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <created xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <customFieldValues soapenc:arrayType="ns2:RemoteCustomFieldValue[3]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                        <customFieldValues href="#id1"/>
                        <customFieldValues href="#id2"/>
                        <customFieldValues href="#id3"/>
                  </customFieldValues>
                  <description xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <duedate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <environment xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <fixVersions xsi:type="ns2:RemoteVersion" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <key xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <priority xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <project xsi:type="xsd:string">MON</project>
                  <reporter xsi:type="xsd:string">fgulotta</reporter>
                  <resolution xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <status xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <summary xsi:type="xsd:string">This is a test ticket.</summary>
                  <type xsi:type="xsd:string">31</type>
                  <updated xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <votes xsi:type="xsd:long" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </multiRef>
            <multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:RemoteCustomFieldValue" xmlns:ns3="http://beans.soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                  <customfieldId xsi:type="xsd:string">customfield_10094</customfieldId>
                  <key xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                        <values xsi:type="xsd:string">4</values>
                  </values>
            </multiRef>
            <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:RemoteCustomFieldValue" xmlns:ns4="http://beans.soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                  <customfieldId xsi:type="xsd:string">customfield_10084</customfieldId>
                  <key xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                        <values xsi:type="xsd:string">27/Jul/11 02:21 PM</values>
                  </values>
            </multiRef>
            <multiRef id="id3" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns5:RemoteCustomFieldValue" xmlns:ns5="http://beans.soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                  <customfieldId xsi:type="xsd:string">customfield_10100</customfieldId>
                  <key xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                        <values xsi:type="xsd:string">Yes</values>
                  </values>
            </multiRef>
      </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to create an issue (requirement) using perl with SOAP::Lite. The key is to build the request using arrays and defining the types using SOAP::Data->type(). I couldn't fill in the fix version using the 'fixVersions' attribute, but I did it through the custom field 'customfield_10040'. You can use the getItem() call to check which one is used in your case.

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->service($URI);
my $token = $soap->login($USERNAME,$PASSWORD);

my $fieldValues = [
   SOAP::Data->type('RemoteCustomFieldValue', {'customfieldId' => 'customfield_10040',
                                               'values' => [
                                                   SOAP::Data->type('string', '10051'),
                                                   SOAP::Data->type('string', '10052')
                                                           ]
                                              }),];
my $affectedValues = [
   SOAP::Data->type('RemoteVersion', {'name' => 'FINS 1.16.1', 
                                        'id' => SOAP::Data->type('string', '10051')}),
   SOAP::Data->type('RemoteVersion', {'name' => 'FINS 1.16.1a',
                                        'id' => SOAP::Data->type('string', '10052')})
                     ];
my $fixedValues = [
                   SOAP::Data->type('RemoteVersion', {'name' => 'FINS 1.16.1', 
                                                        'id' => SOAP::Data->type('string', '10051')})
                  ];
my $customFields    = SOAP::Data->type('RemoteCustomFieldValue', $fieldValues);
my $fixVersion      = SOAP::Data->type('RemoteVersion'  , $fixedValues);
my $affectedVersion = SOAP::Data->type('RemoteVersion'  , $affectedValues);
my $component       = SOAP::Data->type('RemoteComponent', \{'name' => 'CST', 'id' => SOAP::Data->type('string', '10194')});

my $remoteIssueHash = {
    'project'           => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $PROJECT),
    'type'              => SOAP::Data->type('string' => 10),
    'summary'           => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $summary),
    'reporter'          => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $reporter),
    'assignee'          => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $assignee),
    'customFieldValues' => SOAP::Data->type('array'  => $customFields),
    'affectsVersions'   => SOAP::Data->type('array'  => $affectedVersion),
    'components'        => SOAP::Data->type('array'  => $component),
    'fixVersions'       => SOAP::Data->type('array'  => $fixVersion),  ## this doesn't do anything
    'description'       => SOAP::Data->type('string' => $description),
    'environment'       => SOAP::Data->type('string' => 'Some environment'),
};

my $remote_issue = $soap->call('createIssue', $token, $remoteIssueHash);
print Dumper [$remote_issue->faultcode(), $remote_issue->faultstring(), $soap->transport()->status(), $remote_issue->result(), $remote_issue ];
exit();
```

Good luck with that.

Daniel

Comment: You win! The "SOAP::Data->type('RemoteCustomFieldValue', {} )" worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

createIssue takes a RemoteIssue object. The RemoteIssue object has an array named customFieldValues of RemoteCustomFieldValue objects. All good so far. A RemoteCustomFieldValue object has an field named customfieldId (not "id" as you have) and a String array named "values". It looks like $severity is not an array?

All this came from the Java source for RemoteIssue and RemoteCustomFieldValue. SOAP errors are almost always useless in my experience.

~Matt

Comment: I've renamed the id field to "customfieldId" and put the values in arrays with still no luck.

Comment: Updated code example and referred to the Jira source, but I still don't see how the object is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've given up trying to make sense of `SOAP::Lite`. I got badly bitten by that module's unforeseen ways of doing things back in 2005 and have learnt to avoid using it.

Many a times, a simple `LWP` plus `XML::LibXML` to build the DOM is good enough.

You might even be in a position to hardcode the XML document as a string in your program and just interpolate variables. Not pretty, but sufficient in some situations.

Now you're facing a WSDL file and chances are your scenario isn't trivial. (I don't know.)

I only recently learnt of the existence of the excellent Mark Overmeer's [`XML::Compile`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile/) suite of modules. You have to pay respect where respect is due. We had to integrate with a SOAP/MTOM/XOM service, so XML using binary attachments. I didn't have much of a clue about that (bloated enterprise) specification. Using [`XML::Compile::SOAP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile-SOAP/), we got it working in three hours where most of the time was wasted with trivial issues that only had to due with our (silly) trial and error approach. Had we followed the docs, it would have been one hour.

So I highly recommend Mark Overmeer's [`XML::Compile::SOAP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile-SOAP/). It has worked greatly for us.